# Extracting specific data out of big chunk of data

Tags: google-sheets

I want to extract the data in [my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VbOyaMfsbS6Yoz9xUqfNkLqmPyzMxd-K97Dc7vywLm0/edit#gid=1122422322) from this huge paragraph. The data behind and after the highlighted data that I need to extract is fixed all the way with no change at all. I guess it can be a guideline.

I tried using Regextract but for some reason it's showing some extra data with the data that I need and I can't seem to use trim to cut it :(

[image]

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to show code here.

Comment: this is for Google sheet :/

Comment: I need a google sheet formula to achieve the outcome, I also tagged it under google sheets.

Comment: Understood. That doesn't mean you shouldn't show your attempt _here_ and ask a specific question about it. We don't work on other sites.

Comment: Or you might try https://superuser.com.

Comment: ok I added my attempt on the sheet and also as screenshot. thank you for help.

Comment: You didn't read the page I suggested, did you? Screenshots of code won't do.

Comment: Thank you Isherwood, I'll follow your recommendation in the next questions. sorry for any inconvenience caused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this implementation I just tested? It should work alright for your purpose.

```
import re

text = '       2021-06-09 00:58:49   48s                          Redz@gmail.com     selectedPoliyCode: a8b8a620poliList: {"code":"a8b8a620","isPolicyList":true,"poliyChecked":[{"label":["Audio"],"version":"8","results":[{"results":{"action_audio":"violation"},"area_code":"ALL"}],"description":"Bullying statements in","level":"L1","pt":"ccde764f","categories":["Harassment and bullying"],"poliy":"Bullying statements in","language":"en","isRecommend":false,"checked":true,"pseudo":"","tags":["audio"],"code":"a8b8a620","keywords":["audio"],"content":"<span style=\"background: #ffff00;\">Bull</span>ying statements in NPGA","id":"ccde764f_a8b8a620_en"}]} selectedTitle: Bullying statements;pipeline_infos: {"review_target":"mt_music_report_queue","config_key":"mt_music_report","create_task_logid":"","use_hawk2_config":1,"object_id":"6943268167347227394","env":"prod","object_type":"music_report","create_time":1623166571,"fr_idc":"alisg","mos_extra_data":{}}action: Delete      '

pattern_mail = r'(?:\d+s)(.*)(?:selectedPoliyCode)'
pattern_title = r'(?:selectedTitle:)(.*)?;'
pattern_object_id = r'(?:"object_id":")(.*?)(?:")'

mail = re.findall(pattern_mail, text)[0].strip()
title = re.findall(pattern_title, text)[0].strip()
object_id = re.findall(pattern_object_id, text)[0].strip()
```

Note that the text is the one you posted in the spreadsheet. Also, the pattern for mail might be "selectedPolicyCode".
The three variables should contain the desired values.
My solution is in python, but the regex should work the same. Let me know if it works.

mail: (?:\d+s)(.*)(?:selectedPoliyCode)
title: (?:selectedTitle:)(.*)?;
id: (?:"object_id":")(.*?)(?:")

Here you can find them used in the black row of words (formula is there):
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m7Z9R1KKwcvGN0K_2TwOO19KsehfDWIcxoL9potYG7M/edit?usp=sharing

```
mail: =REGEXEXTRACT(B5, "(?:\d+s)(.*)(?:selectedPoliyCode)")
title: =REGEXEXTRACT(B5, "(?:selectedTitle:)(.*)?;")
id: =REGEXEXTRACT(B5, "(?:""object_id"":"")(.*?)(?:"")")
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your contribution <3. I'm working on google sheets actually not python :(

Comment: If it is possible to filter using regex in google sheets, you should be able to use the same regex code I tried.

Comment: ok i updated the sheet, i can use regextract yes, but its showing unwanted data and trim didnt exclude it.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m7Z9R1KKwcvGN0K_2TwOO19KsehfDWIcxoL9potYG7M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: thats excellent @A.M. Ducu, it worked like charm. thank you so much <3

Comment: Glad I could help :)